# Как подключить библиотеку к проекту на C++

Tags: c++, firebase

Мне нужно подключиться к БД Firebird используя IBPP, который я скачал с официального сайта в виде архива. В архиве нет файла .lib, есть только файлы .h и .cpp.

В "Свойства конфигруации" -> "C/C++" -> "Доп. каталоги включаемых файлов" указал папку с заголовочным файлом ibpp.h. Что нужно еще сделать? В include указан путь до этого файла. Собрать .lib чтобы указать в компоновщике?

Код:

```
#define IBPP_WINDOWS
#include "ibpp/ibpp.h"
#include <iostream>

IBPP::Database db = IBPP::DatabaseFactory("localhost", "db.fdb", "username", "password");
db->Connect();
db->Disconnect();
```

Вылетает ошибка: "Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class IBPP::Ptr __cdecl IBPP::DatabaseFactory(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &)" (?DatabaseFactory@IBPP@@YA?AV?$Ptr@VIDatabase@IBPP@@@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@000000@Z) в функции "class IBPP::Ptr __cdecl IBPP::DatabaseFactory(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &)" (?DatabaseFactory@IBPP@@YA?AV?$Ptr@VIDatabase@IBPP@@@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@000@Z).  ConsoleApplication1 C:!FL\36\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj   1"